# Benchmark Configuration - Error:PlanningProblem(null) can't be null

Tags: optaplanner

This question is a continuation of [Implementing a SolutionIO Interface for Benchmarking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37445464/implementing-a-solutionio-interface-for-benchmarking).

In short, i'm working on a problem similar to the NurseRostering one from OptaPlanner. Currently i need to implement a benchmark, where i encountered the error from the link above.

Now that error has been resolved, and i'm getting the error `The planningProblem (null) must not be null.` Based on this i believe that my `solution` is not read properly and i need to make some adjustments. I did some research, did a lot of debugging, with not luck on finding what i need to do.

Below are all the configs,classes and interfaces that i have modified:

CustomBenchmarkIO:

```
public class CustomBenchmarkIO<Solution_> implements SolutionFileIO<Solution_>{

public String getInputFileExtension() {
    return null;
}

public String getOutputFileExtension() {
    return null;
}

public Solution_ read(File inputSolutionFile) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void write(Solution_ solution, File outputSolutionFile) {

}

}

Note:<Solution_> is what i currently have, i tried both <Solution> and <Solution_> , both didn't work.
```

NurseRosterBenchmarkApp:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new NurseRosteringBenchmarkApp().buildAndBenchmark(args);
}

public NurseRosteringBenchmarkApp() {
    super(
            new ArgOption("name",
                    "org/optaplanner/examples/nurserostering/benchmark/BenchmarkConfig.xml"));
}
Note: This is the default NurseRosterBenchmarkApp.
```

NurseRosterConsoleApp - I have my configured the NurseRosteringApp to run only from console.

```
public class NurseRosterConsoleApp extends CommonApp{
protected NurseRosterConsoleApp(String name, String description,    String solverConfig, String iconResource) {
    super(name, description, solverConfig, iconResource);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
// function for reading the solution from a file
public static Solution readSolution(File inputFile, boolean inputXmlType) {
    // reading from a solution xml file
    if (inputXmlType) {
        return (Solution) new NurseRosteringDao().readSolution(inputFile);
    } else {
        Solution solution;
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder(false);
            Document document = builder.build(in);
            XmlInputBuilder xmlInputBuilder = new NurseRosteringImporter.NurseRosteringInputBuilder();
            xmlInputBuilder.setInputFile(inputFile);
            xmlInputBuilder.setDocument(document);
            try {
                solution = (Solution) xmlInputBuilder.readSolution();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Exception in inputFile (" + inputFile + ")", e);
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Exception in inputFile (" + inputFile + ")", e);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not read the file (" + inputFile.getName() + ").", e);
        } catch (JDOMException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not parse the XML file (" + inputFile.getName() + ").", e);
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
        }
        return solution;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File inputXml = new File(Settings.inputFilePath);
    SolverFactory solverFactory = SolverFactory.createFromXmlResource(Settings.SOLVER_CONFIG);
    Solver solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();
    Solution unsolvedNurseRoster = readSolution(inputXml, Settings.inputXmlType);
    NurseRoster nurseRoster = (NurseRoster) unsolvedNurseRoster;
    solver.solve(unsolvedNurseRoster);
    NurseRoster solvedNurseRoster = (NurseRoster) solver.getBestSolution();
    try {
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Override
protected AbstractSolutionExporter createSolutionExporter() {
    return new NurseRosteringExporter();
}
@Override
protected SolutionDao createSolutionDao() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
@Override
protected SolutionPanel createSolutionPanel() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

}
Note: I extended the CommonApp class, and added all of the    unimplemented methods,
but it still didn't work. Also i configured the constructor to be the same as the OptaPlanner one 
(although i think it's for the GUI, correct me if i'm wrong).
```

BenchmarkConfig - It's the same as the previous question

```
<plannerBenchmark>
<benchmarkDirectory>local/data/nurserostering/location</benchmarkDirectory>
<warmUpSecondsSpentLimit>5</warmUpSecondsSpentLimit>
<inheritedSolverBenchmark>
    <problemBenchmarks>
        <solutionFileIOClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nurserostering.persistence.CustomBenchmarkIO</solutionFileIOClass>
        <inputSolutionFile>data/nurserostering/import/importTest/Input0.xml</inputSolutionFile>
    </problemBenchmarks>
```

**My questions here are:**

**1. Am i missing something regarding configuring the solver?**

**2. Regarding the Exporter - Is it necessary to add all of my planning 
entities so that the solution will be created?**

**3. Will my NurseRosterConsoleApp cause problems with the benchmarking?**

**4. Where is the solution created?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i solved my problem. By now i thought that some methods read the `Solution` in the background, but since i debugged it a lot of times, i realized that i need to do that.

**The solution to the problem was simple:**

In the **CustomBenchmarkIO** class, in the **Read** method i just typed what i use to read the `Solution` in my other main( where i normally run it), and it worked.